# Setup equation to find surface area. Confused as to use x or y. Is this setup for surface area correct?

Tags: integration

I am trying to setup equations for finding the surface area when the equation is rotated around the x or y axis. is this right? wolfram gives me two different answers for each setup. Where am I going wrong? Wolfram gives me 9.79564 for i) and 13.721 for ii).

Say I have an equation:

$$y = \tan^{-1}x$$ from $0 \leq x \leq 2$

My hint in my book is to setup the equation for x so:

$$\tan y = x$$

and when $ x = 0$, $y = 0$ and when $x = 2$, $y = \tan^{-1}2$

and $\frac{dx}{dy} = \sec^{2}y$ which will be used for arc length.

i) So when rotating around the x-axis, I need a y either as y itself or as expressed in terms of x. If I express it as y, I need a dy right?

I also have to change the limits of integration here because the original limits were given for x but we're integrating with respect to y right?

$$SA = 2 \pi \int_0^{\tan^{-1}2} y \sqrt{1 + (\sec^2y)^2} dy$$

ii) So when rotating around the y-axis, I need a y either as x itself or as expressed in terms of y. If I express it as y, I need a dx right?

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$
$$SA = 2 \pi \int_0^{2} x \sqrt{1 + (\frac{1}{1 + x^2})^2} dy$$

Comment: Please ask a clear question rather than explain what you're doing (which may or may not be appropriate for the question).  WHAT surface area (for instance)?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork noted, edited.

Comment: Your integrals are correct (except the second one should have a $dx$)

Comment: I wonder why my wolfram is giving me different answers....ohhh because they are supposed to be different!

Comment: @ShubhamJohri feel free to jot an answer and note that different integral answers are correct here and I'll give you credit!

Comment: I think I misunderstood something about what limits of integration to use... if the arc length formula that I use uses dy, then the limits of integration have to be for y. Conversely, if the arc length formula I use uses dx, then the limits have to be for x right?